# Finding a journal for specialised, interdisciplinary research

Tags: publications, journals, interdisciplinary

Assuming I decided what specific thing I want to research, how I can find journals suitable for my research?

For example, I am interested in *query by humming* in computer science. Will a signal-processing journal accept such a paper? Will a pattern-recognition one do, assuming I actually use pattern recognition algorithms?

Seems like there are very few (2–3) computer-science–music journals available. Can I only publish in these?

Comment: You are getting way ahead of yourself. First, you do the research. Then you figure out which journal will be suitable, since that will also depend on how string the results are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In which journals are the papers you are citing published? Which journals do these papers, in turn, cite? Which conferences and workshops have been around on your topic and where were the contributions to them published? These are all potential venues for your paper.

Also make sure to ask around among colleagues who work in the field and ask your supervisor.

You can always informally inquire with the editor of a potential journal outlet whether your paper falls within the scope of that journal. They might perhaps even be so kind as to suggest alternatives, in case they don't deem your paper pertinent.

Comment: Exactly - a critical aspect is to ask!